# Entity Framework - How to load empty children

Tags: entity-framework

Am getting started using Entity Framework and have run into a problem.

Say I have 2 tables in my database. One called Agent that contains an ID and a password and another table called AgentDetail that contains more information about the Agent. However, there might not be a corresponding AgentDetail record for every Agent record.

I have these 2 classes to represent those 2 tables:

```
public class Agent
{
    public string AgentId { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual AgentDetail AgentDetail { get; set; }
}

public class AgentDetail
{
    public string AgentDetailId { get; set; }
    public string AgentName { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
}
```

Using EF I can add data to the database OK. I can also retrieve data OK when there is a corresponding record in both tables.

```
        var agents = from a in context.Agents
                     select a;

        return View(agents.ToList());
```

However I get a NullReferenceException in my view when rendering values within AgentDetail if that record doesn't exist in the AgentDetail table.

Now that's totally expected as there is no AgentDetail record.

My question is how do I get EF to create an AgentDetail with empty values when the record doesn't exist in the table.

Can I add an empty child object in the LINQ query - something like:

```
        var agents = (from a in rb.Agents
                      select new
                      {
                          AgentId = a.AgentId,
                          Password = a.Password,
                          AgentDetail = a.AgentDetail == null ? new AgentDetail() : a.AgentDetail,
                      }).ToList();
```

(the above doesn't work however as I get the following message:

The entity or complex type 'Models.AgentDetail' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.)

Comment: Are you wanting EF to actually create the AgentDetail if one doesn't exist, record so one will be persisted in the database?

Comment: Hi Mark, No I'm not bothered about that. I just wanted to know the best way to handle child data that doesnt exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really don't want to have an 'empty' item artificially added, because then (without some bending backwards), that object will be attempted to be persisted to the database.

The best thing to do is split off a partial view for the sub-data, and simply check for `null` before trying to read values from it.

Comment: Hi Andrew. What you're saying makes perfect sense. Thanks.